# How does iodine react with amylose and amylopectin, and can iodine colorimetry be used to determine the ratio between the two starches?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Based on some of the methods of studying starches in rice I looked at, I found that there are two general distinctions:

- ones that focus on the ratio between amylose and amylopectin
- ones that focus just on amylose, measuring percentage content

The former included methods such as electrophoresis, amperometric, potentiometric and spectrophotometric procedures. The latter used procedures primarily based on colorimetry using iodine.

Due to technical constraints, I think that colorimetry will be a realistic option for my task.

However, I am unsure about the differences in measurement for the two types:

- given that iodine creates different colors with amylose and amylopectin, can this be used to calculate the ratio?
- if the sample contains more than just amylose and amylopectin (such as rice flour, rather than starch), can the iodine colorimetry procedure still be used?

Example of a procedure that uses iodine colorimetry: 
[C. M. Sowbhagya; K. R. Bhattacharya (1971). A Simplified Colorimetric Method for Determination of Amylose Content in Rice. , 23(2), 53–56. doi:10.1002/star.19710230206]

Example of a procedure using electrophoresis: 
[José Manuel Herrero-Martínez; Peter J. Schoenmakers; Wim Th. Kok (2004). Determination of the amylose–amylopectin ratio of starches by iodine-affinity capillary electrophoresis. , 1053(1-2), 227–234. doi:10.1016/j.chroma.2004.06.048 ]

*I have done as much research as I can on this, but I am not fully familiar with the field. Please forgive any misunderstandings.

Comment: If there are different colours, there can be analyzed absorbance at 2 or more wavelengths. ( 2 to differentiate them, 3rd and more to subtract the background ) , implying some standards are available.